# Upsert data with a dynamic field name

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I just try to do something simple with Mongo but it doesn't work:

I want to upsert datas in an object like: `module.xxx.yyy` then I tried many things like :

```js
UsersRights.upsert({
 condoId: condoId,
 userId: manager._id,
}, {
 condoId: condoId,
 userId: manager._id,
 module: {
  [defaultRight.xxx] : {
   [defaultRight.yyy] : defaultRight.default
  }
 }
});
```

but when I want to add a new `xxx` or a new `yyy`, it will erase and replace the entire `module` object and not only add a new key.

I also tried this :

```js
UsersRights.upsert({
 condoId: condoId,
 userId: manager._id,
}, {
 condoId: condoId,
 userId: manager._id,
 ["module." + defaultRight.module + "." + defaultRight.right] : defaultRight.default,
});
```

but the server show me an error like: `MinimongoError: Key module.xxx.yyy must not contain '.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following form:

```
YourCollection.upsert({
    _id: id, (can be other selectors as well)
}, {
    $set: setter
});
```

Setter is an object you create before and should have the following form:

```
const setter = {};
setter[`${#1Level}.${#2Level}`] = data;
```

Where `#1Level` & `#2Level` are vars naming the fields you want to modify or to add.